# open source VDI solution

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vdi

looking to build a 10 node to eventually 50 node VDI solution. 
the only OS on the desktop will be ubuntu ( or some other linux )

looking for easy setup administration, and remote administration etc.

will probably just use diskless PC as clients for now, but would want a solution that can accommodate thin-clients as well, and maybe there its just XDMCP from the server.

must be completely open source ( no VMware )

thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

Two options that present themselves immediately:

1. Don't do VDI, do a terminal server! [NoMachine NX](http://www.nomachine.com/) would be the leader in that space for Linux. However, it's not *entirely* open source.
2. [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/) is an open source offshoot of the formerly GPL NX protocol.
3. **EDIT:** Do VDI with [Ulteo](http://www.ulteo.com/home/).

Comment: is NX a licensed product ? or open source ?  also what about LTSP ?

Comment: [Certain](http://www.nomachine.com/sources.php) [parts](http://www.nomachine.com/documents/technology/pdf/building-components-3.x.pdf) of it are. Take a look at [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/) and also look at the [Wikipedia page for the NX protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology).

Comment: That's "two options" with a numbered list of three? :)